# Warning: Could not create server TCP listening socket *:26380: bind: Address already in use, redis sentinel

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

616:X 04 Dec 2023 21:59:04.445 # Warning: Could not create server TCP listening socket *:26380: bind: Address already in use
616:X 04 Dec 2023 21:59:04.445 # Failed listening on port 26380 (tcp), aborting.

Here I use windows 10, I have created 3 Ubuntu instances using WSL2, I am exploring redis sentinel service, master-slave is working fine. When I tried redis sentinel service Master is working fine, but when I run slaves, I get above error. I tried all the thing changing windows firewall setting, changed port value in sentinel.conf file, earlier it was 26379, then I changed to 26380.Still I am getting the same error. Because of this error I could not see log at slave side and ultimately redis sentinel is not working in my computer.

sentinel.conf

sentinel monitor ecomm 172.26.75.225 6379 2
port 26380

I disabled windows firewall, then created an inbound rule that allows traffic on the Redis port 26380, stopping redis server then starting again, but nothing could solve the error.

Comment: The error is telling you what's up - you're running something else on port 26380.  Perhaps another sentinel, perhaps something else.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-do-i-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-tcp-or-udp-port-on-windows) to help figure it out.

Comment: when i run master, i got, this message , Running in sentinel mode
 Port: 26380
 PID: 1512